# Redirect within Ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, caching, header

I need to redirect an Ajax call without letting the client know.

getPage.php is an application which returns html etc. for a given query.

**getPage.php?hash=interesting-article-title** and **getPage.php?page=3** returns the same.

To avoid the client from having to cache both of these I would like **getPage.php?hash=interesting-article-title** to REDIRECT to **getPage.php?page=3** via PHP header 301 and location.

I tried doing this and it returns nothing. The ajax call does not seem to want to be redirected.

Does anyone have any idea what could solve this double-cache problem?

I would like to use 301 redirects because they are cacheable. This way the browser would automatically call **page=3** when it is told to fetch **hash=insteresting-article-title**.

Code examples:

```
    function handleInit(event) {
        if (event.path != "/") {
            var hash = event.path.replace(/\//,"").replace(/\?/g,"");
            getPage(hash);
            currentState.hash = hash;
        } else {
            currentState.id = 1;
        }
        SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, handleChange);
    }


    function chapter_forward() {
        if (!freeze) {
            freeze = true;
            getPage(currentState.id - 1);
        }
    }


    function ajax_data(id) {
        return typeof(id) == "string" ? "hash=" : "page=";
    }

    function getPage(id) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: getPage.php,
            data: ajax_data(id) + id.toString(),
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 2000,
            error: function() {
                $("#space-3").html('40104 - Request Timeout');
            },
            complete: function() {},
            success: function(result) {
                handleContent(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

The reason I need the redirect to happen is because I get the id from a HASH when the user uses his back and forth browser buttons.

When the user simply navigates back and forth I simply add +1 to the current id.

getPage.php returns something like this:

```
{"article_id":"3","hash":"music-in-your-ear","title":"Music in your ear.","html":"Blah blah article 3","modified":"Fri, 20 Mar 2009 02:46:00 GMT"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you use the Ajax? Are you calling Ajax within your page to load the next page, or are you trying to use Ajax to redirect? Do you have some example code?

Comment: Could you provide some code examples?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83990/is-it-the-filename-or-the-whole-url-used-as-a-key-in-browser-caches/84010#84010), the correct behaviour for browsers is to not cache urls with query params.

I dont know if 301 redirect even works when you are basically accessing the same url.

I suggest you go through your code and only use one of those links if they return the same thing.

Comment: I really wouldn't use both if it was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache, mod-rewrites and a rewrite map file are an excellent way to solve this server side assuming your hash is a predefined list of terms that map to the specified IDs.

I am assuming you are doing this for SEO benefits?

Comment: Indeed I am using Apache and they are predefined. However the process of adding items into mod-rewrite would have to be dynamic for users to be able to do it via a form.
Could you please define SEO. Thanks!