# Expires cache for same script across multiple pages

Tags: http-headers, http-caching

I have a script that is used across multiple pages on my site. I want to set the expires header so that browsers cache it and it doesn't get downloaded every time. That's ok and I understand how to do that, but I don't quite know how the browser works.

Does the browser cache it according to its path and then is it smart enough to know that any page requesting the script should use the cached version, or is there an association between the script and the page and therefore it would have to be cached against each page?

Answer (score 0):

**In the browser cache, there is no connection between the URL and the requesting page**. Browser cache keys contain the path and sometimes the query string (see [Is it the filename or the whole URL used as a key in browser caches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83990)).

That's why Google recommends using their [Libraries API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/libraries/devguide.html): If every page that requires a specific version of jQuery pointed the browser to fetch the library from Google, the browser would fetch it only once for www.xyz.com and then re-use it from its cache for www.abc.com.