# Multiple JavaScripts - Both work separately, but if used together second doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load 2 scripts (or more) on one page and Only the 1st one is working.  I do not have access to edit the javascript so I cannot make changes to it.

Here is the code:

```
<div style="z-index:0; min-height:600px;">
    <script language="javascript" src="http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1202&amp;sitenumber=0&amp;tid=ticket_results2&amp;evtid=2175269"></script>
    <noscript></noscript>
</div>
<div style="z-index:0; min-height:600px;">
    <script language="javascript" src="http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1202&amp;sitenumber=0&amp;tid=ticket_results2&amp;evtid=2175270"></script>
    <noscript></noscript>
</div>
```

When I run the page, the 1st one loads fine but the second one does not.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Jsfiddle links:

Not working: http://jsfiddle.net/6E6ZC/

Working seperately 1: http://jsfiddle.net/5LZ8d/

Working seperately 2: http://jsfiddle.net/SQ778/

Comment: anything in your console?

Comment: Are you sure the site that you are calling can handle two scripts in such rapid succession? It might simply be that you need a small delay between the two calls.

Comment: @Ewald Yes, they can handle it.

Comment: Your URLs are not valid. You've got HTML-escaped "&amp;" entities where there should be just `&`.

Comment: Maybe your second script does not produce any visible result, but there is no reason why it should not be loaded. My guess is, it defines the same functions and/or variables and the second instance overwrites the first.

Comment: @Pointy  I tried changing this and it didn't have any affect on the results

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ssc is not defined ?bid=1202&sitenumber=0&tid=ticket_results2&evtid=2175269&t=1390499331668:68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***DO NOT REMOVE CACHE.***

What is happening is that the browser thinks it is being asked to retrieve the same file on each request.

I had the same issue and here is how to resolve it.

Add one more querystring paramater like I have. I added the `'&t='+ new Date().getTime()`

```
'/api/drawings?a=e&f=img&id=' + eID + '&t=' + new Date().getTime()
```

Will work like a champ!

---

**Here is a way to dynamically add the scripts to the page, and this is a FOR SURE WILL WORK WAY.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         setTimeout(function () {

        var script1 = document.createElement('script'),
            script2 = document.createElement('script');

        script1.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script1.setAttribute('id', 'script1');
        script1.setAttribute('src', 'http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1202&sitenumber=0&tid=ticket_results2&evtid=2175269&t=' + new Date().getTime());

        script1.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script1.setAttribute('id', 'script2');
        script1.setAttribute('src', 'http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1202&sitenumber=0&tid=ticket_results2&evtid=2175269&t=' + new Date().getTime());

        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script1);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script2);

            },500);

</script>
```

**With the script above you do not have to add the scripts statically. Just let the script that I've provided run.

This is all assuming that you're not attempting to load two JS files with the same exact script in each file. If your trying to continually check for changes you only need one file and an interval. "setInterval(function(){//this would be something totally different and a lot more work})"

Comment: Add this to the src= ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how you're loading the JS. If it is static scripts that you've added to the page then you'll have to either add then dynamically or document.ready which out the src for each file.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a javascript guy... Can you show me what you mean in your answer?  The page is a php page and the only variables that will change when calling the scripts are the evtid variables.

Comment: I've updated my answer to help you. By using the setTimeout you'll be assured that the DOM is fully loaded because the setTimeout will not run until the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Have you tested this?  I just tested the code you provided and I unfortunately still get the same result.

Comment: Now... neither of them are loading.

Comment: Since cache is most likely not the problem, this very convoluted solution will not solve it.

Comment: I apologize I added code that I've prototype, the newly added code is  primitive raw JavaScript.

Comment: I noticed that when I load the page and then refresh quickly, neither of them load.  But I have only been able to get both to load at the same time.

Comment: They will now, or something else is going on.

Comment: I've tried this and had no success.  I don't know where to go from here.  I was able to get both to load using iframes, but the links inside the iframes open in the iframe which we cannot have :(  I can't think of another work around.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a caching problem. Try setting headers on the JavaScript so that it doesn't allow browser caching.

Comment: Since the URLs are different, I can't see how this could cause a cache problem.

Comment: @kuroineko Since most browser caches ignore parameters on javascript include urls, it is very likely that this is a caching problem. It's a common issue with loading scripts, especially AJAX.

Comment: I don't think so. I did some testing a few months ago with all major browsers, and a single char of difference was enough to get another cached copy. See [this discusson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83990/is-it-the-filename-or-the-whole-url-used-as-a-key-in-browser-caches) to dispell a common misconception.

Answer (score 0):

There is no caching problem and both scripts load correctly with a http 200 status message. When used separately, they produce results but when used together the 2nd one doesn't produce any result.

This could be happening as 2nd script expects something in the page where it can put its contents, but it doesn't find there s it was removed by 1st script. This looks to me as the most probable cause.

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/6E6ZC/

```
<div style="z-index:0; min-height:600px;">
    <script language="javascript" src="http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1202&amp;sitenumber=0&amp;tid=ticket_results2&amp;evtid=2175269"></script>
    <noscript></noscript>
</div>
<div style="z-index:0; min-height:600px;">
    <script language="javascript" src="http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1202&amp;sitenumber=0&amp;tid=ticket_results2&amp;evtid=2175270"></script>
    <noscript></noscript>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser/version?  I have tried several browsers with no success

Comment: Mac, Chrome 32. I'm setting up an example on jsfiddle to get some of the confusions out of the way.

Comment: Are you running the file directly in web browser by double clicking or running it inside a web server? - this could be imp. factor.

Comment: Firefox for me shows the first one in your jsfiddle and the 2nd one loads a loading image

Comment: I observed that they work separately so am editing my answer to make our understanding better.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I feel bound to answer this one after seeing so many wrong turns.

Cache or not is a non-issue. Even if the browser does cache the request (and it most likely will, since the URLs are exactly the same), it all depends on what the loaded code is supposed to do.

Unless the code changes the name of its functions and/or variables on the fly or does other very smart things, including basically the same code a second time will very likely overwrite the first copy, thus doing nothing more than if the file had been included only once.

I would be very surprised if the guys at `http://tickettransaction.com` did design an interface relying on the user adding some random junk at the tail of the URL to allow a second execution of the very same request result on the same page.

Would they have wanted to support such an usage, they would simply have added a `cache-control: no-cache` or equivalent directive in their response headers.

But after all, I've seen weirdest things in my programmer's life.
Maybe the guy at `tickettransaction.com` was badly hungover the day he coded that or something?

---

To get rid of this cache false problem, simply open your dev tools and watch the network traffic. You will most likely see the request being fetched twice from the cache (or once from the server and once from the cache if you hit Ctrl+F5).

If you really want to have your request fetched twice from the server, simply disable the cache, and make sure you get a full server transfer twice.

Having jumped through all these hoops, you will very likely witness the same result, namely the second response code overwriting the first.

---

Last update.

Just to get rid of this caching non-issue, I added a variable parameter in the URL.
I used the dev tools to make sure the browser was NOT caching the second request.

Cache being dealt with once and for all, I did have a look at the code of this mysterious script:

```
document.write('<!--MA-WS-C23-->');
document.write('');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://seatics.tickettransaction.com/jquery_tn.js"></' + 'script>');
 document.write('');


    var TN_ticketResults = null;

    function TN_populateTicketData(data) {
            TN_ticketResults = data;
        if(typeof TN_tryCreateTicketTable == "function")
            TN_tryCreateTicketTable();
        }

    (function() {
        var cysct = document.createElement("script");
        cysct.type = "text/javascript";
        cysct.src= '//tickets.tickettransaction.com/Tickets/ByEvent/?' + 
            'eventId=2175270&websiteConfigId=669&sort=retail&callback=TN_populateTicketData';
        cysct.async = true;
         var pnode = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        pnode.parentNode.insertBefore(cysct, pnode);

    })();


 document.write('');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://seatics.tickettransaction.com/swfobject_tn.js"></' + 'script>');
 document.write('');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://seatics.tickettransaction.com/maincontrol_tnservice_tn.js" ></' + 'script>');
 document.write('');

    // ppcsrc 
    var cookie_tn_ppc_src ='';
    var tn_cookies = '; '+document.cookie + ';';
    var cookie_ppc_src_start =tn_cookies.indexOf('; tn_ppc_src=') + 13;
    if(cookie_ppc_src_start != 12)
        cookie_tn_ppc_src = '&ppcsrc=' + tn_cookies.substring(cookie_ppc_src_start, tn_cookies.indexOf(';', cookie_ppc_src_start));
    var acct_start =tn_cookies.indexOf('; rcaid=') + 8;
    if(acct_start != 7)
        cookie_tn_ppc_src +='&rcaid=' +  tn_cookies.substring(acct_start, tn_cookies.indexOf(';', acct_start));

    //map css suppliment
    var fileref=document.createElement("link"); 
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet"); 
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    fileref.setAttribute('href', 'http://seatics.tickettransaction.com/tnservice_map_suppliment_tn.css');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref);

    //maps 
    var webParms = {
        swfMapURL    : "http://seatics.tickettransaction.com/FenwayPark_Baseball_2013-04-24_2013-04-24_1120_tn.swf",
        staticMapURL : "http://seatics.tickettransaction.com/FenwayPark_Baseball_2013-04-24_2013-04-24_1120_tn.gif",
        mapShellURL  : 'http://seatics.tickettransaction.com/mapshell_tn.swf'
    };

    webParms.vfsFilterAnimate = 'vertical-list';
    webParms.vfsImageAnimate = 'vertical-list';
    webParms.vfsEnable = 'selected-hover';





    var TN_docFinishedLoading = false;
    window.onload = function() {

        ssc.EH.buyTickets = function(buyObj) {
            var purchaseUrl = 'https://tickettransaction2.com/Checkout.aspx?wcid=669&e=' + escape(buyObj.tgSds) + cookie_tn_ppc_src + '&treq=' + buyObj.buyQty + '&SessionId=' + makeGuid();
            if (typeof AppendToPurchaseUrl == "function") {
                try {
                    purchaseUrl = AppendToPurchaseUrl(purchaseUrl);
                } catch(e) {
                }
            }

            if (typeof PopupCheckOut == "function" && PopupCheckOut())
                window.open(purchaseUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes');
            else
                location.href = purchaseUrl;
        };

        TN_docFinishedLoading = true;
        TN_tryCreateTicketTable();
    };

    var TN_onEmptyEvent = TN_onEmptyEvent || function(title) {

        $("#tn_loading").css("display", "none");
        $("#ssc_listAndMapDiv").css("display", "none");
        $("#tn_tblNoResults").css("display", "");

    };

    function TN_tryCreateTicketTable() {
        if (TN_docFinishedLoading && TN_ticketResults) {
            if (TN_ticketResults.TicketsAvailable) {
                $("#tn_loading").css("display", "none");
                ssc.loadTgList(TN_ticketResults.TicketData, webParms);
            } else {
                TN_onEmptyEvent('Boston+Red+Sox+vs.+Tampa+Bay+Rays+on+Tue%2c+Apr+29+2014');
            }

        }
    }


    function makeGuid() {
        var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        var guidLength = 5;
        var guid = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < guidLength; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            guid += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
        }
        return guid;
    }

    function GoToOtherGame(eventid) {
        if (eventid != '')
            document.location = 'ResultsTicket.aspx?evtid=' + eventid;
    }




 document.write('<table class="tn_results_header">    <tr class="tn_results_header_title">        <td class="tn_results_header_title">            Boston Red Sox vs. Tampa Bay Rays        </td>        <td class="tn_results_header_venue">            Fenway Park            <br />            Boston, MA        </td>        <td class="tn_results_header_datetime">            Tue, Apr 29 2014            <br />            7:10 PM        </td>    </tr>        <tr class="tn_results_header_divider">        <td colspan="3" class="tn_results_header_divider">        </td>    </tr></table>     <div id="tn_loading" style="text-align:center;"><img src="//s3.amazonaws.com/TNService/Images/spinner.gif"/></div><div id="ssc_listAndMapDiv"></div><table style="display: none;" id="tn_tblNoResults" class="tn_results_notfound" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">    <tr class="tn_results_notfound">        <td class="tn_results_notfound">            There is currently no online inventory available for this event.            <br />            <br />            Please contact <span class=\'tn_results_notfound_name\'>                TicketSociety.com</span> at <span class="tn_results_notfound_phone">                    (866) 459-9233</span> or <a class="tn_results_notfound_email"                        href="mailto:CustomerSupport@TicketSociety.com">                        CustomerSupport@TicketSociety.com</a> to check availability for this event.        </td>    </tr>    <tr valign="middle" class="tn_results_divider">        <td class="tn_results_divider">        </td>');
 document.write('    </tr></table>');
```

As expected, it does some inline Javascript that actually WORKS twice. You can see it when looking at the 2 lines header before the big table. They indeed appear twice.
You can also inspect the DOM and you will see that your second div is populated with a skeleton table, but the table is never filled.

Unfortunately, the code also defines some variables and functions that are overwritten by the second include. The result is an Ajax request that cannot succeed (basically because the code was not designed to handle the same Ajax request twice on the same page).

Comment: Interesting, I was hoping that it is something I could control on my end.  I have been racking my brain for a workaround.  I even went as far as to add them in IFrames, the only issue is that the links open in the iframe, not the browser.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: My pleasure. Before trying to throw various spanners into the cache's cogwheels, I suggest you try to disable the cache manually from the dev tools, just to make sure this has something to do with cache (and I bet it hasn't).

Comment: I tried disabling the cache and I was still not able to load both.

Comment: What do you mean? You did not manage to force the browser to fetch the request from the server twice, or you did witness the same results even though the request was fetched twice from the server?

Comment: When I disabled the cache, the problem did not change, I still was able to load the first one but the 2nd one would not load.

Comment: Here are the warnings and errors produced by Dev Tools:
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1202&amp;sitenumber=0&amp;tid=ticket_results2&amp;evtid=2175269

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1202&amp;sitenumber=0&amp;tid=ticket_results2&amp;evtid=2175269

Comment: Just read your last update, that doesn't seem too optimistic. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Kuroineko Bravo! Wonderful answer but I think the poster has just went postal with you're provided answer.

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com That was my goal right from the start (exits scene with evil cackle...)